# Wi-Fi not reconnecting after rebooting the router

Tags: raspbian, wifi, networking, dhcp

> This question (and answer) relate to an obsolete OS and not relevant to ANY current system.

I have a Raspberry Pi B+ which is connected to my modem/router via a TP-Link TL-WN725N usb adapter. It works fine, however if i turn off the router and than back, the Raspberry doesn't reconnect automatically. I need to plug and unplug the adapter back.

This is the content of /etc/network/interfaces:

```
interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

I have a static ip reserved by the router

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem I think.
Try the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file without the full `auto wlan1` entry so your config file looks like this:
    interfaces
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

If this doesn't works, you can try the `wpa.conf` file instead of `wpa_supplicant.conf` file.

Comment: However i don't use wlan1, the adapter is wlan0.

Comment: Then you can try the '/etc/wpa.conf' file instead of *wpa_supplicant.conf'.
The file contains 'network={ ssid="" psk="" }'

Comment: What are the differences?

Comment: I am not completely sure. It works fine for me since I changed it. Maybe I should try again the wpa_supplicant.conf. Can't find the blog entry for this again, sorry.

Comment: Checked now, I have no /etc/wpa.conf file, the ssid and password file is /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems on two of my networked Pis.  On both, the issue was that I had done in-place upgrades on the systems and by mistake ended up with two network control packages running at the same time on both systems.

On one system I had dhcpcd and dhclient, on the other I had dhcpcd and wicd.

For the system with dhclient, the solution was:

**Find out if dhclient (or wicd) is in use**

```
ps -elf | grep dhclient
```

**Then remove it**

```
sudo apt remove --purge dhclient
```

**Then reboot**

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

or
sudo reboot

I followed a similar process on the system that had dhcpcd and wicd. There were multiple wicd packages running and I needed to remove all of them.

Comment: MatsK, thank you for the editing!